# StopIteration en generator pipelines

Tags: python, pipeline, generator

```
def positive(seq):
    for x in seq:
        if x >= 0:
            yield x
       
def every_other(gen):
    for x in gen:
        yield x
        gen.__next__()
      
def double(seq ):
    for x in seq:
        yield x
        yield x
  
seq = range(-5, 5)
# seq = range(-5, 6)

pos = positive( seq)
skip = every_other(pos)
two = double(skip)

[x for x in two]
```

Cuando ejecuto este código con `seq = range(-5, 6)`, optengo `[0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4]`.
Cuando lo ejecuto con `seq = range(-5, 5)`, obtengo:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "<stdin>", line 4, in every_other  
StopIteration  
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>  
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in double  
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

Yo esperaba en ambos casos `[0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4]`.

¿Por qué me salta la StopIteration?
Yo esperaba que la captaría el proceso de formación de la lista, y obtendría el mismo resultado en ambos casos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un generador es una función que retorna un *lazy-iterator*: una función que devuelve valores (como una lista) sin tenerlos todos presentes al mismo tiempo en memoria.

Lo normal es usar los generados en un `for`:

```
for x in two:
    # hacer algo
```

pero también puedes ir sacando los elementos uno por uno con `__next__()`, o con la función `next(iterador)`:

```
x = two.__next__()
```

Los iteradores señalan el fin de la secuencia levantando la excepción `StopIteration`. El `for` lo maneja automáticamente, pero si usas `__next__()` directamente, tendrás que hacerte cargo de la situación:

```
try:
    x = two.__next__()
except StopIteration
    pass # Hacer algo apropiado
```

La diferencia de resultado entre ambos `range()` está en

```
def every_other(gen):
    for x in gen:
        yield x
        gen.__next__()
```

Si tienes un número par de elementos en `gen`, funciona perfecto: lees uno, te saltas el otro y los vas consumiendo de dos en dos. Pero si tienes un número impar (tres, por ejemplo), en la primera iteración consumes dos elementos, luego el `for` pide el tercero, entra a la iteración y falla al intentar obtener el cuarto.

**Solución**

Hay que capturar la excepción y desecharla.

```
def every_other(gen):
    for x in gen:
        yield x
        try:
            gen.__next__()
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 3):

La razón ya te la ha explicado perfectamente @CandidMoe, junto con una solución basada en capturar e ignorar la excepción que produce `.__next__()` (nota: invocar directamente a un "dunder method" no se considera buena práctica, en vez de `gen.__next__()` sería preferible poner `next(gen)`, aunque en el fondo será lo mismo).

Propongo aquí otra solución que evita usar `next()` (o `.__next__()`) usando solamente bucles `for` que se ocupan ellos mismos de gestionar esa excepción (finalizando el bucle cuando ocurre).

La idea es sencilla, hacer `yield` solo si el índice del elemento es par:

```
def every_other(gen):
    for i,x in enumerate(gen):
        if i%2 == 0:
           yield x
```

Y por aportar algo más novedoso, también se podría utilizar la función `itertools.islice()` en la forma siguiente:

```
from itertools import islice

def every_other(gen):
    yield from islice(gen, 0, None, 2)
```

`islice()` es otro generador, que recibe un iterable como primer argumento (el cual puede ser un generador como demuestra el código anterior) y después los parámetros típicos de un slice `[inicio:fin:paso]`. En este caso le paso 0 como inicio, `None` como fin (iterará hasta que se agote `gen`) y 2 como paso.

Observa también cómo useo `yield from` para pasar directamente el control a este iterador, en vez de escribir la (igualmente válida pero más torpe sintaxis) `for x in islice(...): yield x`

## BONUS: Más programación funcional

Haciendo uso de otras herramientas en itertools se puede intentar reescribir cada una de las funciones sin usar ni un solo bucle `for`, sino usando en cambio `yield from` y delegando en otro generador.

La función que sólo devuelve positivos es fácil, y ni siquiera requiere de itertools:

```
def positive(seq):
   yield from filter(lambda x: x>=0, seq)
```

La que va tomando uno sí y uno no, ya la escribí antes. La repito aqui por coherencia:

```
from itertools import islice
def every_other(gen):
    yield from islice(gen, 0, None, 2)
```

La que va repitiendo duplicados los elementos de otro generador es la más farragosa:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat
def double(seq):
   yield from chain.from_iterable(zip(*repeat(tuple(seq), 2)))
```

Ésta hace uso de `repeat(it, n)` que concatena n veces el iterador `it`. En este caso, si le pasarámos `seq` concatenaría el generador, pero una vez agotado el primero el segundo no daría ya más elementos, por lo que "congelamos" usando `tuple(seq)` la secuencia para poder repetirla.

El resultado de este uso de `repeat()` será un iterable sobre el que se puede iterar dos veces, y las dos veces devuelve lo mismo (la secuencia `seq`). Por ejemplo, si `seq` devuelve la secuencia `0, 2, 4`, entonces mi `repeat()` devolverá `(0,2,4)` en la primera iteración y `(0,2,4)` otra vez en la segunda (sería internamente la misma tupla).

Paso estos dos elementos como parámetros a `zip()` desempaquetándolos con un `*`. Por tanto zip en cada iteración tomará un elemento de cada uno de esos dos iterables, e irá devolviendo tuplas de este estilo: `(0,0)`, `(2,2)`, `(4,4)`.

Para convertir esa secuencia de tuplas (que es un iterable a su vez) en la secuencia de enteros que hay dentro, uso `chain.from_iterable()` que espera recibir una secuencia de iterables (efectivamente la secuencia de tuplas lo es), y va devolviendo los elementos de cada uno de esos iterables de uno en uno, y cuando se agote un iterable pasa al siguiente. Así primero devolvería 0, después 0, y agotada la primera tupla pasa a la siguiente y devuelve 2, después 2, etc. logrando así el objetivo que nos proponíamos.

Vale, admito que este último es horrible y que sólo lo he puesto para practicar más programación funcional "pura". Pero funciona:

```
[x for x in double(every_other(positive(range(-5,5))))]
```

Sale `[0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4]`